# How to access iPod from gtkpod in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ipod, ipod-touch

Ubuntu 10.04 recognizes my iPod Touch because when I connect it an icon pops up on the desktop and I can also play the files from rhythmbox. I installed gtkpod and tried to access the iPod but it doesn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04 automatically mounts your iPod when it is plugged in; mounting it somewhere else is a waste of time.

The default path is `/home/$user/.gvfs/$ipodname` where `$user` is your username and `$ipodname` is the name assigned to your iPod when you set it up on iTunes.

FYI: you will need to sync with iTunes at least once.

Answer (score 0):

I found this website - sometimes it works, but it can crash on occasion and is slow.

> [How to sync an iPod with Ubuntu 10.04 using GTKpod and ifuse](http://randomitblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-sync-ipod-with-ubuntu-1004-using.html)

If I run Windows in VMware Player I can also access the iPod there just like in Windows.